# Utilizar un array como parámetro para consulta en MYSQL

Tags: php

Quiero realizar una varias consultas en un ciclo teniendo como condicional el array[$correos] y guardar los resultados en otro array, pero solo se me guarda el último valor encontrado y concretamente son dos resultados en este caso. ¿Cómo podría hacer lo anterior descrito?

```php
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($correos)-1; $i++){
    $documento_destinatarios = $link->query("SELECT usu_docume FROM usuario WHERE usu_email = '$correos[$i]'");
}


$row = mysqli_fetch_array($documento_destinatarios, MYSQLI_NUM);
printf ("%s/ %s\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Actualización

Gracias a los comentarios de @A.Cedano también se puede replantear todo de este modo:

```php
$correos_destinatarios = '"'.rtrim(implode('","',$correos), ',').'"';
$documentos_destinatarios = $link->query("SELECT usu_docume FROM usuario WHERE usu_email IN($correos_destinatarios)");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($documentos_destinatarios)) {
    echo $row['usu_docume']." / ";
}
echo "\n";
```

Con esta solución se evita sobrecargar MySQL con demasiadas consultas consecutivas y pasar el resultado de la única consulta a PHP para que haga el resto mediante el bucle `while` recorriendo todas las filas de resultados de la consulta.

Por otra parte, segun comenta el OP, el array $correos puede contener un registro vacio al final de su array, por lo tanto al hacer el implode() de sus elementos nos va a generar una coma de más, que la eliminamos con rtrim() de este modo:

```
$correos_destinatarios = '"'.rtrim(implode('","',$correos), ',').'"';
```

a la vez que agregamos comillas a todos los elementos del array para que queden entrecomillados y no se produzcan errores al usar la claúsula IN en SQL.

### Repuesta inicial

Debes ponerlo todo dentro del bucle, sino vas sobreescribiendo la variable $documento_destinatarios hasta que sale del bucle, donde solo conserva la asignación de la consulta del último ciclo.

```php
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($correos)-1; $i++){
    $documento_destinatarios = $link->query("SELECT usu_docume FROM usuario WHERE usu_email = '$correos[$i]'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($documento_destinatarios, MYSQLI_NUM);
    printf ("%s/ %s\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudaste mucho.

Comment: Lo propio sería escribir la consulta así: `WHERE usu_email IN(implode(',',$correos))` de eso modo, ejecutarías una sola consulta, no `N` consultas, ganando en rendimiento. Evidentemente, al hacer eso, sobra el `for`, luego, para leer los resultados sí usas un `for` o mejor un `while`.

Comment: Puede ser, pero por el momento sólo veo que quiere obtener el valor de `usu_docume` de un conjunto de correos, que pueden ser 2 o más ... en ese caso, en vez de mandar a ejecutar `query()` N veces es mejor una sola ejecución, de lo contrario el código no estará optimizado. Cada ejecución de `query()` tiene su precio.

Comment: @A.Cedano Sí sí, no leí lo que dijistes despues y entendi mejor la consulta, que genera varios registros que se pueden volver a recorrer para lo que sea, por eso acabé borrando mi comentario

Comment: Exacto, una vez ejecutada `query()` una sola vez, dado que se usará `IN` podrás tener `N` filas, las que arroje la consulta, y para leer esas filas puedes usar un `while` aplicando el `fetch` que quieras. O, incluso, puedes agrupar los datos si quisieras usando `GROUP_CONCAT`, pero esto último ya depende del uso posterior, si necesita un array con los datos finales no convendría usar `GROUP_CONCAT` quizá ...

Comment: Realmente me preocupaba la optimización pero no se me ocurría otra forma, aprendí mucho. Lo intentare inmediatamente.

Comment: @masterguru No me muestra ningún resultado :/

Comment: Claro, no sabemos como es tu array $correos... quizas tienes un registro de más vacio al final de todo que te genera esa coma de más

Comment: Realmente el código no es mío, sino que me asignaron terminarlo. siento generar confusiones.

Comment: Funciona!! Te lo agradezco muchísimo, por la paciencia y por la gran ayuda. Eres un genio.

Comment: Uf, al fin! :-)  Me alegro que ya te haya servido!  Saludos!